# How can I store the fibonacci sequence in a vector during each recursive call?

Tags: c++, recursion, beginner, vectors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void getUserNum(int &);
int rFib(int n);
void dispSeq(std::vector<int> &vRef);

int main()
{
    int userNum;
    getUserNum(userNum);
    rFib(userNum);  
    return 0;
}

void getUserNum(int &refVal)
{
    std::cout << "Enter a positive integer:\n";
    std::cin >> refVal;
}

int rFib(int n)
{
     static std::vector<int> fib;
     static bool baseReached = false;
     fib.push_back(n);

     if (baseReached)
     {
             dispSeq(fib);
     }

     if (n <= 1)
     {
        baseReached = true;
        return n;
     }
     else
     {
        return rFib(n-2) + rFib(n-1);
     }
 }

void dispSeq(std::vector<int> &v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << v[i] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Asking how to do something is best done on SO. Though a good code review here will definitely push you in the correct direction.

Answer (score 2):

Its normal to put parameter names even in the declarations:

```
void getUserNum(int &);
```

We use this to help us identify what the function is doing.

In C++ the `'*'` and the `'&'` are part of the type information. So it is usual to push these left towards the type rather than the name. Note this is basically the opposite of `C` conventions. But `C++` is much more rigorous on types and safety than `C`.

```
void dispSeq(std::vector<int> &vRef);

// Normally in C++ code I would expect this:
void dispSeq(std::vector<int>& vRef);
```

Be careful with your use of out parameters.

```
void getUserNum(int &refVal)
```

It seems more natural to return a value from a function then get sombody inside to set an external value via a reference (not unheard of and it will depend a lot on the context). But in this situation I would return a value. It will then make using the code eaiser.

```
 int userNum   = getUserNum();
```

Error Checking (especially input from a human) needs to be more rigorous.

```
void getUserNum(int &refVal)
{
    std::cout << "Enter a positive integer:\n";
    std::cin >> refVal;
}
```

If a user enters a non positive value things will go bad. If the user inputs a string the value of `refVal` I believe is left unaltered (which leaves your code with an uninitialized variable).

```
int getUserNum()
{
    int result;

    // user input is done by the line.
    // so read a line at a time and validate it.
    std::string  line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::stringstream  linestream(line);

    int result;
    if (linestream >> result)
    {
         // The read worked.
         // Lets check the user did not type ofther crap on the line.
         //
         char x;
         if (!(linestream >> x))
         {
               // Reading more data worked. This means the input was good.
               // As the user typed a number followed by some other stuff
               // like  56.4   (the .4 is illegal)
               //       5Plop  (the Plop is illegal)
               //
               // The the above would have successfully read a value into
               // `x` this with the ! it would have failded and this
               // this condition would not have been entered.

               // We only return if:
               //    1. We read an integer. 
               //    2. There is no other data on the line except white space.
               return result;
         }
    }
    // invalid input
    std::cout << "Stupid user input aborting\n";
    exit(1); // Reading failed.
             // Leave as an exercise on how to repeat the question.
             // You can also compress that very verbose if statement into a single
             // line without it looking too bad.
}

// Single line if
if ((linestream >> result) && !(linestream >> x))
{   return result;
}
```

In Fib() you should probably not use recursion. Prefer a while loop. Loop from 0 upto the point you want to reach. This makes using a vector easy. You can also start from where you left off last time rather than 0.

```
int fib(int n)
{
     static std::vector<int>   values = {1,1};
     if (n < values.size()-1) }return values[n];

     int start = values.size();
     for(int loop = start; loop < n; ++loop)
     {
          values[loop] = values[loop-2] + values[loop-1];
     }
     return values[n];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Loki Astari has covered the important points, so I won't repeat those.  I'll just address recommended integer and size types:

- For `getUserNum()`, you're specifically asking the user for a positive number.  So, instead of reading into an `int`, use an `unsigned int`.  You should still include validation.  This also better reveals your intent to the reader.

  You could also instead have `main()` get this input.  That way, if you don't want to hound the user for proper input, you could just return `EXIT_FAILURE` if the first attempt fails.
- `size_t` is *not quite* close enough for `std::vector` (and `std::size_t` is more C++-like anyway).  Although it is an STL container, it's best not to assume that each one is of this type.  [For all STL containers, prefer `size_type` as it's more portable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409396/1950231):

  ```
  standardContainerType::size_type;
  ```

  For your vector:

  ```
  std::vector<int>::size_type;
  ```

  In `fib()`'s for-loop, use this type for `i`:

  ```
  // this could go before the loop
  //   if it looks too long to go inside
  std::vector<int>::size_type i;

  // since this is an integer type,
  //   post-increment is okay here
  for (i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
  {
      // ...
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks Jamal again for your help, slightly confused about the data types mentioned will do some reading on the subject.

Comment: @ao2130: Sounds good.  I'd say the second point about `size_type` is more important.  The `unsigned int` just looks nicer, but it shouldn't cause problems.